# Unable to add couchdb4j dependency in gwt maven project

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I have followed the following link to create a maven project [Create Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540510/create-a-gwt-maven-project). Like creating a simple gwt project and then configure for maven. Till here it goes simple without any problem.Like we are couchdb as our database, I have been trying to add couchdb dependency.

Problem 1: Tried out many ways but unable to add couchdb 4j dependency.

Error: Missing artifact `com.google.code:couchdb4j:jar:0.1.2`

Now, want the solution for this.

Query: Is there any other way to work with maven with GWT.

[image: pomimg]

---

**EDIT 1**
I got a pom.xml from a link where they have couchdb4j in it, but still my basics function of create document(), getDocument() are not been received. The couchdb4j is not added to maven dependencies as seen in build path.

**Is there some difference with client and server side use of maven dependencies?**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>couchdb4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>couchdb4j</artifactId>
    <name>CouchDB4J</name>
    <version>0.3.0-i386-1</version>
    <url>http://code.google.com/p/couchdb4j/</url>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>logkit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logkit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jruby</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jruby</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
            <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-beta2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>codehaus.snapshots</id>
            <name>Codehaus Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</url>
            <snapshots>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>My Nexus</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

For the time being i added it as it is.

Still unaware with the problem that why its not adding the dependencies?

What exactly I have to do for adding couchdb4j jar from dependencies?

Comment: couchdb4j is not available in the Standard maven repository

Comment: then how will i be able to use its classes

Comment: You have to put the jar into your local repository

Comment: Do all the jars have their respective maven dependency?

Comment: no most libraries are available at maven Standard repository but not all

Comment: currently not finding gwt-validation api-1.0.1.GA-sources

Comment: Why you need the  it. That contains only the sources?

Comment: thank you. got it. Can you suggest me where should i search the needed dependency

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. probably a temporary fix, add this repo to your pom

```html
    <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>repo-wso2</id>
          <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/abdera.couchdb.temporary</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
```